# Trig equation, solve for x

Tags: trigonometry

I couldn't solve the question : $3\cos^2 x-2$ for $x\in(180,270)$, evaluate $2\sin(x/2+30)$

My answers were

1. $x=35.26+360n$
2. $x=324.74+360n$

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Math.SE. Can you clarify what you mean (e.g. are you looking for $3\cos^2 x-2=0$?)?  Also we can help you better if you can say what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

We don't need the exact value of $x$

As $180^\circ<x<270^\circ,$

$\displaystyle(1):\cos x <0,\sin x<0,$

and  $\displaystyle(2): 90^\circ<\frac x2<135^\circ\implies 120^\circ<\frac x2+30^\circ<165^\circ \implies \sin\left(\frac x2+30^\circ\right)>0$

$$\text{Now as } \cos^2x=\frac23\implies \cos x=-\sqrt{\frac23}\text{ and }\sin x=-\sqrt{1-\frac23}=-\sqrt{\frac13}$$

Now, $\displaystyle \cos2A=1-2\sin^2A\implies\sin\left(\frac x2+30^\circ\right)=+\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(x+60^\circ)}2}$

Use $\displaystyle \cos(A+B)=\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B$